# What does interface with two functions type declarations means and how to use it?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

```
interface MyInterface {
    (select: string): number;
    (element: number): string;
}
```

How do I use above interface? What is the use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the function has two different signatures, or in other wise overloading.
For example:

```
interface MyInterface {
    (select: string): number;
    (element: number): string;
}

let fn: MyInterface;
fn = (obj): any => {
    // do something 
    return null;
}

let str = fn(3); // type of str is string
let num = fn("string"); // typeof num is number
let error = fn(false); // error as false is neither string or number
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20MyInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(select%3A%20string)%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(element%3A%20number)%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20fn%3A%20MyInterface%3B%0D%0Afn%20%3D%20(obj)%3A%20any%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09%2F%2F%20do%20something%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20str%20%3D%20fn(3)%3B%20%2F%2F%20type%20of%20str%20is%20string%0D%0Alet%20num%20%3D%20fn(%22string%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20typeof%20num%20is%20number%0D%0Alet%20error%20%3D%20fn(false)%3B%20%2F%2F%20error%20as%20false%20is%20neither%20string%20or%20number))